# Loading config data from json file in AWS template.yaml for deploying to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml

When deploying a simple function to AWS Lambda, I want to use a `config.json` (external file) to fill some of the fields of the `template.yaml` that I use to configure my AWS Lambda deployment. My directory structure is

```
my_project 
    my_package\
        my_source_code.py
    template.yaml
    samconfig.toml
    config.json
```

Here `samconfig.toml` contains some deployment parameters related to the environment from which I deploy, `template.yaml` contains all the resource definitions (e.g. `AWS::Serverless::Function`, `AWS::Serverless::Api`, and `AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping`), and `config.json` contains some package dependent configuration settings, like the package version number or the service name for this particular package.

What I want to do is to load the version number from `config.json` and pass it as an environmental variable for the `AWS::Serverless::Function`. But I cannot find a way for doing that. What I tried to do is this:

```yaml
# template.yaml
Resources:
    my_lambda:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            Handler: ...
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    VERSION: ${file(config.json):version_number}
```

where

```
# config.json
{
    "version_number": "1.0"
}
```

However that doesn't work and when I load `VERSION` from the environment, I get to see the string `"${file(config.json):version_number}"`.

I cannot find any resource online describing how to do that (admitting that I find the AWS documentation hard to comprehend).

I did find documentation on [`Fn::GetParam`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html#w2ab1c21c18b9), but that needs an artifact name to load the json data from and I don't know what that would be in my context.

> NOTE: I use AWS CLI to deploy to AWS cloud using `sam build --use-container --manifest <path/to/requirements.txt>` and `sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset` as build and deploy commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from [the thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2054#issuecomment-762550286) that iagotb shared, I updated my approach to tackle this issue: work with [AWS parameters in `template.yaml`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

- Add the data that I want to insert as a parameter in `template.yaml`
- Refer to that parameter elsewhere in `template.yaml`
- Override that parameter's value during deployment using the `--parameter-overrides` flag of `sam deploy`

As the tools that I deploy are deployed automatically via a Jenkins environment, and I don't have control over that environment and what libraries are installed there, the suggested solutions in the linked thread didn't directly work for me. In the end I followed these steps to add the parameter overrides to my deployment:

- create `build.py` file that is called during Jenkins deployment
- automatically create `.samparams` from `build.py`
- load `.samparams` into variable during Jenkins deployment
- pass variable to `sam deploy`

Below I will explain in more detail what I did.

### Original desired solution

What I originally wanted, was to directly plug data from a json file in my AWS template and format that data correctly in the template, for example by doing something like:

```
VERSION: ${file(config.json):version_number}
```

However, this is simply not possible.

### Creating `.samparams`

During the Jenkins deployment, I automatically create `.samparams` from `build.py`. In this process, I can fully control all information sources (a json, another config file, or just hard-coded in `build.py`) to collect the necessary data to create the parameter overrides.

Next I create the file`.samparams` according to the following formatting rules:

- parameter name-value pairs are written as: `parameter_name=parameter_value`
- names and values are **not** escaped with double quotes
- multiple pairs are separated by spaces
- the whole string should be on 1 line

**For example**, let's say we have three parameters we want to override:

- "Version": "1.4"
- "Env": "prod"
- "AppName": "my_example_app"
  then a correct `.samparams` file contains the following line:

```
Version=1.4 Env=prod AppName=my_example_app
```

### Passing `.samparams` to `sam deploy`

The Jenkins deployment is controlled via a Groovy file. In the deployment stage I execute the following two commands:

```
SAM_PARAMS = sh (script: "(cat ./.samparams)", returnStdout: true)

sh """
(
. ${PYTHON_VENV}/bin/activate;
sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --parameter-overrides ${SAM_PARAMS}
)
""".stripIndent()
```

And with this, the parameter overrides are correctly passed to `sam deploy`.

> **NOTE:** When supplying parameter overrides via the command line, AWS will ignore all existing parameter overrides in the `samconfig.toml` file. If you have any overrides listed there, make sure to merge them into `.samparams`. This is a limitation of AWS.

### Alternative: update `samconfig.toml`

Prior to above solution, I explored the possibility to dynamically update an existing `samconfig.toml` file where other AWS configuration settings are stored. While this is more powerful, as you can define parameter overrides for each AWS command and environment, I abandoned that approach due to the complexity of working with the parameter overrides field and the (limited) capabilities of toml parsers in Python.

1. In `samconfig.toml` the parameter overrides should be in a similar format as above `.samparams` format. However the parameter values should be surrounded by double quotes and the double quoted should be escaped:

   ```ini
   parameter_overrides = "Version=\"1.4\" Env=\"prod\" AppName=\"my_example_app\""
   ```
2. The toml parsers I tried are (were) quite finicky with the backslashes, which made it very cumbersome and difficult to create correct parameter overrides strings.
3. Toml is expressed as a dict in Python. So, if you want to create a field in a table that doesn't exist yet, you need to check and potentially create all intermediate tables before you can create the overrides field.

   > For example, if you want to create
   >
   > ```py
   > config['default']['deploy']['parameters']['parameters_override']
   > ```
   >
   > then you need to check whether `default`, `deploy`, and `parameters` exist (and create them if they don't) before you can assign a value to the `parameter_overrides` field. toml parsers don't do that for you.
4. Due to the deep nesting, your code becomes very verbose, very quickly.

Given all the above and that for my use case I only needed to supply parameter overrides to `sam deploy`, I abandoned this approach and went for the `.samparams` file approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are some alternatives to pass parameters from file. All of them use sam cli parameter `--parameter-overrides`

You can use jq or cat to read from file and pass parameters from file.

Overhere you find an example with jq:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2054#issuecomment-762550286

Comment: Thanks for the help. Based on the thread that you linked, I started experimenting with different ways of adding the parameter overrides. In the end I had to choose a different way to deploy given the way that my deployment process to AWS is organized. I will add an answer, explaining what I did to solve this.